# How do I install bundletool?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

Although [the docs](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) mentioned

> If you haven't already done so, download bundletool from the GitHub
> [repository](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases).

However, the repo contains only a jar file. How do I install it so that I can run with the 'bundletool' command just like the docs' example?

Comment: meanwhile you can run it using `java -jar bundletool-all-0.6.2.jar`

Comment: I wonder how many people came here from https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases - how hard would it be to add an install/use section to the repo

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can create an alias (or doskey on Windows), e.g.

`alias bundletool='java -jar bundletool-all.jar'`

Comment: I thought it was a command line tool you could install as first. This is what I did in my terminal right now. Thanks

Comment: Is this an exact command in Windows command line?  'alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: As mentioned in the parenthesis, it's called doskey on Windows.

Comment: I am on linux and I have jdk8 installed, this shows `Error: Unable to access jarfile bundletool.jar`

Comment: I just typed in cmd: doskey bundletool=java -jar C:\Users\user\bundletool-all-1.14.0.jar $*

  And then bundletool worked for me

Answer (score 171):

If you have [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bundletool) installed simply run `brew install bundletool` and the alias will be set up for you as well. It did the trick for me.

Comment: If you don't have `brew`, with this instruction you can install it https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Comment: Results in "Error: No available formula with the name "bundetool"

Comment: Do you have brew installed, @AndroidDev?

Comment: Yes I do. It also took a very long time to update itself, after which it attempted to install bundletool but with no success. Brew 2.1.7 running on a Mac.

Comment: @Johann you missed an l in bundletool....

Answer (score 47):

Another alternative is access [Bundletool release page](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) and download the **bundletool-all-[LAST-VERSION].jar** file into some directory.

After that you could run it on the directory calling:

```
java -jar bundletool-all-0.10.2.jar your_arguments_here
```

If you want, rename the jar file to **bundletool.jar**, then run it calling:

```
java -jar bundletool.jar your_arguments_here
```

If you don't want call `java` every time, you can create an alias for that, and after that run quicly:

```
alias bundletool='java -jar bundletool-all.jar'

bundletool your_arguments_here
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem, I used bundletool to extract an apk from aab files

Answer (score 22):

On a mac, it can be easily done using homebrew

`brew install bundletool`

then you can run commands like this

`bundletool install-apks --apks=release.apks`

you can use the command below to generate apks

`bundletool build-apks --bundle=aab_path.aab --output=release.apks`

The above command generates apks file which can later be extracted to give various apk files.

Answer (score 16):

To make shortcut/alias in Windows 10, in cmd run:

```
@doskey bundletool=java -jar <youPath>\bundletool-all.jar $*
```

You must be already added Java folder path to system environment variables or just google it.

Comment: I updated my answer by append $*,thanks for you comment.

Comment: after restarting pc, this command need to paste again in cmd , windows

Comment: got this to work `@doskey` is what we need.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently for Linux you have to download the jar from: https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases

and then run `java -jar <PATH_TO_JAR> ...`

to simplify things you can add in `/usr/local/bin/` a `bundletool` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
exec java -jar "$HOME/path/to/jar" "$@"
```

and `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bundletool`

Now you can run `bundletool` from wherever you want

Comment: This answer is the easiest if you are running LINUX and have already got the java executable on your PATH (which is very likely if you are doing Android development).

Answer (score 2):

As for me, on windows, I just set `assoc` and `ftype` so that `.jar` will open with `java -jar`

First I download `bundletool.someversion.jar` into some folder under PATH env (so that it would exposed)

Open cmd as admin and link `.jar` to `jarfile` with cmd `assoc .jar=jarfile` (actually can be any name, make it jarfile is just convention in the same way as other file)

Then `ftype jarfile=^%JAVA_HOME^%\bin\java.exe -jar %1 %~2`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype

Then we could execute `bundletool.someversion.jar` or any jar to open it as java directly

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have

> brew.

Install it somewhere, but not in your project directory
`npm install bundletool`

and then you can run

`java -jar node_modules\bundletool\.bundletool\bundletool-1.0.0.jar`

Although a global `npm install` might be a better option.